# Disable admin application for django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run the django development server and its failed with below error.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my/virtual/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/my/virtual/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/my/virtual/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/my/virtual/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/my/virtual/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 469, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (admin.E403) A 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates' instance must be configured in TEMPLATES in order to use the admin application.
```

this is `django-rest-framework` application and it has no admin application.

How to say `django runserver` to not run admin application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to change how `manage.py runserver` behaves, but to reconfigure your Django site. Essentially, you want to do the reverse of [enabling the admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#overview).

The most important step is to remove `django.contrib.admin` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`. You should also remove `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` from your `MIDDLEWARE` if it is present.

You may also want to remove the auth, messages, and sessions apps, though you may need them for other reasons. You'll have to make that call yourself based on what your application does.